# Create Network option missing under Wifi for P2P ad-hoc networking (I'm a developer using Xamarin build host)

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, ad-hoc

My goal is to use the P2P wireless networking so the Xamarin editor can deploy on the Mac for development and testing

As of the latest version of Big Sur the option to have a P2P network seems to have been removed, which is unfortunate since while at a hotel, I can't have these two laptops directly connect to each other (P2P routing between adjacent devices isn't working) on the Hotel wifi.

Is there a Terminal option or some other idea to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

Enable/tick "**Show legacy networks and options**" in...
`System Preferences > Network > Wi-Fi > Advanced > Wi-Fi` 
(see image below)
...for the option to "Create Network..." to re-appear in the AirPort menu item.
Or in 
`System Settings > Network > Wi-Fi > Advanced` for Ventura.

See also: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mh11937/mac
https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchl98b9beb6/11.0/mac/11.0

[image: screenshot]

PS/note: After pressing "OK", it's easy to miss the "Apply" button.